# Term for check-in location

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What is a general term for a check-in location? Specifically this is a location where people can be assigned.  They include offices, deployment areas, staging areas, site-locations, warehouses, command centers and trailers.  These locations can also hold equipment and inventory. Unfortunately the only thing I can come up with that isn't too specific is *location*.

Comment: Please could you edit the question and include some more context? For example, is this for a Foursquare type check-in, or a package delivery application?

Comment: its for emergency response application to assign workers site-locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about *rendezvous point*, or *muster point* (in times of emergency)?

Comment: 'Muster', or mustering', as fun as it sounds, is archaic, and recognizable only by Tolkien readers.

Comment: @Mitch I don't think it's *that* outdated.

Comment: OK. 'Archaic' may be a bit extreme. 'pass muster' isn't terribly uncommon, and I'll grant that it might be used more often in military circumstances (though I just don't know).

Comment: @Mitch I would say that the military idea is a likely hypothesis.

Comment: But meeting/rendezvous/muster point is more for a _meeting_ of a number of equal people, but the OP is looking for where there is an authority that a number of people one arrives at to do something. I guess I'm stuck on 'check-in location'.

Comment: @Mitch: This [evidence from NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=muster+point&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows that it's quite the opposite - **muster point** is becoming increasingly common. Doubtless because of ever-increasing elf & safety and fire regulations requiring that such points be identified and test evacuations performed.

Comment: @Fumble: does ngram show a difference between BrE and AmE? 'muster point' is very new to me (an AmE speaker).

Comment: @Mitch http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=muster+point&year_start=1950&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3 That's the AmE Ngram.

Comment: @Mitch: Mahnax has done it for you, but for the future note that where the NGram page shows *from the corpus xxxx* under the search term(s), you can select American or British from a drop-down list to dynamically restrict what's being graphed. But note that this starts to get a bit tenuous unless there are a large number of instances involved. Also, the underlying Google Books dataset is less than totally reliable about classifying texts as UK or US (it gets quite a few dates on individual texts wrong too, but not enough to matter for large-scale trends)

Comment: Thanks Mahnax. @Fumble: so comparing English vs American (from Mahnax's NGram) and ignoring all difficulties with NGrams, BrE has max 0.0000016 and AmE max 0.00000009 (what the units are I don't know). So BrE has roughly 17 times more instances. But it's hard to tell the absolute number of instances (both graphs are pretty jaggy which leads me to believe the n is low.

Comment: @Mitch: Well you get the same list of about 1300 actual instances if you click on the rightmost "total" hotspot (NGram rescales the graph, but it doesn't change the viewable list of instances when you filter for UK or UK), so I suppose that'll be less than 100 US instances as against over 1200 UK. Well, I just calculated it, so say 75 for the US. Not much, I know, but probably enough to swamp any UK/US misclassifications. They both show the same increase, which is all I cared about anyway - I like the pictures better than the maths though, I must admit! :)

Answer (score 3):

It might depend on the specific context, but the most general term I can think of is *sign-in desk*. Similar phrases are *registration desk* and *check-in desk*. For something that has a greater sense of urgency, you could use *rally point*, though that may not obviously imply the idea of "checking in".

Answer (score 2):

I think "station" would be appropriate, especially if they are fixed locations where people are assigned to perform a task.

Answer (score 1):

> Specifically this is a location where people can be assigned. They
>   include offices, deployment areas, staging areas, site-locations,
>   warehouses, command centers and trailers. These locations can also
>   hold equipment and inventory.

Sounds like a *base* to me (as in *"Report to base."*)